# Checking equality up to transpose in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, equality, transpose

Given two multidimensional arrays in numpy of the same shape (in my case they are tensors where every dimension is equal, so the shape would be `[2,...,2]`) I would like to test whether one can be transformed into the other using some transpose operation. Is there an easy way to do this?

To be specific, given arrays `a` and `b` return whether there exists a list of indices `i` such that `a = np.transpose(b,i)`, or even better whether `np.allclose(a,np.transpose(b,i)) == True`

Comment: Having answered a number of `transpose` questions, my guess is that you'll have to systematically test all `i` until you hit one that fails.